# Filter UDF Function stop working on Dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Sheets in the Workbook. Where Sheets("Data") contains 3 Columns picture is attached below.

[image]

then i have Sheets("Return Result") contains data picture attahced below

[image]

Now i am using below Filter UDF to return the Column A from Sheet("Data") values those matched based on Column B and C from Sheet("Data") but its not working i hope someone can look at this and help to figure out the problem.

```
=FILTER_AK(Data!A:A,(Data!B:B='Return Result'!B2)*(Data!C:C='Return Result'!A2))




Function FILTER_AK(Where As Range, Criteria1 As Range, Criteria2 As Range, Optional If_Empty) As Variant
    Dim Data, Result
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    
    ' Create space for the output (assuming the output range is the same size as input cells)
    ReDim Result(1 To Where.Rows.Count, 1 To Where.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Clear
    For i = 1 To UBound(Result)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Result, 2)
            Result(i, j) = ""
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Count the rows to show
    RowCount = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(Criteria1)
        If Criteria1(i, 1) And Criteria2(i, 1) Then
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Empty?
    If RowCount < 1 Then
        If IsMissing(If_Empty) Then
            Result(1, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNull)
        Else
            Result(1, 1) = If_Empty
        End If
        GoTo ExitPoint
    End If
    
    ' Get all data
    Data = Where.Value
    
    ' Copy the rows to show
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        If Criteria1(i, 1) And Criteria2(i, 1) Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Return the result
ExitPoint:
    FILTER_AK = Result
End Function
```

Comment: You have only one criteria in the call but the function need two. Either divide the criteria in the call, or modify the function to input only one criteria.

Comment: I already tried with Single criteria but the output is error

Comment: Criteria2 not get a range input. This is the first cause of the error. There can be other errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls. try this.

The problem that in the function call the criteria is an array. Therefore in the function it must be a Variant. The function is an array function need use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to set it in the cell.

```
Function FILTERAKX(Where As Range, Criteria1 As Variant, Optional If_Empty) As Variant
    Dim Data, Result
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    
    ' Create space for the output (assuming the output range is the same size as input cells)
    ReDim Result(1 To Where.Rows.Count, 1 To Where.Columns.Count)
    ' Clear
    For i = 1 To UBound(Result)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Result, 2)
            Result(i, j) = ""
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Count the rows to show
    RowCount = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(Criteria1)
        If Criteria1(i, 1) Then
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Empty?
    If RowCount < 1 Then
        If IsMissing(If_Empty) Then
            Result(1, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNull)
        Else
            Result(1, 1) = If_Empty
        End If
        GoTo ExitPoint
    End If
    
    ' Get all data
    Data = Where.Value
    
    ' Copy the rows to show
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        If Criteria1(i, 1) Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Return the result
ExitPoint:
    FILTERAKX = Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

- Built-in function `Filter` is a good option.

```
=FILTER(Table2[Name],(Table2[Date]=F2)*(Table2[Locations]=E2))
```

[image]

- If Excel (lower version) doesn't support Filter, please try array formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[Name], SMALL(IF((Table2[Date]=F2)*(Table2[Locations]=E2), ROW(Table2[Name])-MIN(ROW(Table2[Name]))+1, ""), ROW(1:999))), "")
```

[image]

Comment: Excel 2016 does not have built-in function.

Comment: Array formula is an option too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution but i am lookign for UDF to achieve this.

Comment: UDF can be used to get the expected output. But it has to be used an array formula coz it returns more than one values.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different modification of this function from me:

```
Function FILTER_AK(Where As Range, Criteria1 As Variant, Optional If_Empty) As Variant
Dim Data, Result
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, nc As Long

' Verify if declared 'where' range is used
Set Where = Intersect(Where, Where.Parent.UsedRange)

' Create space for the output (assuming the output range is the same size as input cells)
ReDim Result(1 To Where.Rows.Count, 1 To Where.Columns.Count)

' Get all data
Data = Where.Value

' Copy the rows to show
nc = UBound(Data, 2)  ' number of columns
k = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
    If Criteria1(i, 1) Then
        k = k + 1
        For j = 1 To nc
            Result(k, j) = Data(i, j)
        Next j
    End If
Next i

' Empty?
If k = 0 Then
    If IsMissing(If_Empty) Then
        Result = CVErr(xlErrNull)
    Else
        Result = If_Empty
    End If
Else
    ' ReDim result
    Result = Application.Transpose(Result)
    If nc = 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve Result(1 To k)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve Result(1 To nc, 1 To k)
    End If
    Result = Application.Transpose(Result)
End If

' Return the result
FILTER_AK = Result
```

End Function

In the new Excel, it returns the result in the form of a dynamic array, in the older version you can use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after selecting as many cells as you expect the results.
Or you can call the function so that 1 result is displayed each time. Then you copy the formula as long as the results appear.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(filter_ak(Data!A:A,(Data!B:B='Return Result'!B$2)*(Data!C:C='Return Result'!A$2),"NA"),ROW(A1)),"")
```